# Python (source build), cant get tensorflow working

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip

I build python versions 3.6.10 and 3.8.2 from source on Ubuntu 18.04 and can't get pip to properly install tensorflow in virtual environments of either one

**[python3.6.10]**

pip --version -> 20.1

python -c "import struct; struct.calcsize('P')* 8 --> 64

> pip install tensorflow
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

or

> pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
>
> ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

**[Python3.8.2]**
tensorflow intsalls with pip, but get core dumps when building model

```
 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
 ])
```

> python: ../Objects/typeobject.c:3707: excess_args: Assertion `PyTuple_Check(args)' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]

```
pip debug --verbose (for python3.6)
.
pip version: pip 20.1 from venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
sys.version: 3.6.0 (default, May  9 2020, 20:11:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
sys.executable: venv36/bin/python3
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: UTF-8
sys.platform: linux
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
'cert' config value: Not specified
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
  appdirs==1.4.3
  CacheControl==0.12.6
  colorama==0.4.3
  contextlib2==0.6.0.post1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  distlib==0.3.0
  distro==1.5.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  html5lib==1.0.1
  ipaddress==1.0.23
  msgpack==1.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  packaging==20.3
  pep517==0.8.2
  progress==1.5
  pyparsing==2.4.7
  requests==2.23.0
  certifi==2020.04.05.1
  chardet==3.0.4
  idna==2.9
  urllib3==1.25.8
  resolvelib==0.3.0
  retrying==1.3.3 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  setuptools==44.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  six==1.14.0
  toml==0.10.0
  webencodings==0.5.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)

 Compatible tags: 69
  cp36-cp36dm-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-cp36dm-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-cp36dm-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-cp36dm-linux_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-none-linux_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-linux_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py36-none-linux_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py3-none-linux_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py35-none-linux_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py34-none-linux_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py33-none-linux_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py32-none-linux_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py31-none-linux_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py30-none-linux_x86_64
  cp36-none-any
  py36-none-any
  py3-none-any
  py35-none-any
  py34-none-any
  py33-none-any
  py32-none-any
  py31-none-any
  py30-none-any
```

Comment: Which platform are you using? (Like processor and system board).

Comment: uname -a: 
Linux ThinkPad 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.15 , gives the same no matching distribution

Comment: Please include the output of pip debug --verbose in your question. For the version of python that does not show any tensorflow wheels available

Comment: updated. I downloaded the whl file and renamed it to have -cp36-none.any.whl, it did install but when importing tensorflow, I get an error (Failed to load native Tensorflow runtime) [ undefined symbol: PyModule_Create2]

Comment: can you create a new virtual environment with python 3.8 and install tensorflow?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, for 3.8, pip installs tensorflow without any indication of sort of problem, but it core dumps when used (i.e tf.keras.layers.Dense(..) from above)

Comment: sorry did you mean i should try 3.8 as opposed to 3.8.2?